# Node js TLS uncaught error on connection fail? How to catch?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl

It seems to me that there is no way to catch a failed connect with node tls.

```
tls.connect(port, host, options, function(){
    // on connected
})
```

Since the code is async, I can't just wrap it into try catch. And I don't seem to find an event that signals a failed ECONNREFUSED condition. http://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_connect_options_callback

Instead the process just crashes and exits. Although I was able to catch it with uncaughtException handler. But I was not able to figure out a way to recover from the error from that handler. Don't even know which connection it was that failed when program gets there.

So how do we catch a failed connect?

Answer (score 8):

The `tls.connect` method returns a stream object that you should be binding an `error` handler to.

To make it clearer:

```
tls.connect(port, host, options, function(){
  // on connected
});
```

is short for this:

```
var stream = tls.connect(port, host, options);
stream.once('secureConnect', function(){
  // on connected
});
```

So you need to add another handler to listen for errors instead of successful connections:

```
var stream = tls.connect(port, host, options);
stream.once('secureConnect', function(){
  // on connected
});
stream.on('error', function(err){
  // on error
});
```

Comment: This is precisely what I thought, but stream.on('error', fn) doesn't seem to be called on ECONNREFUSED.

Comment: Nevermind my comment, I was doing http request at the same time and the ECONNREFUSED originated from it. I have newest node.js and tls.connect()'s stream's on('error', fn) does the trick like it was supposed to!

Answer (score 0):

`tls.connect()` creates a new client connection to the given `port` and `host`. `tls.connect()` returns a `tls.TLSSocket` object.

You can use the following code to handle the error.

```
var options = {
host: 'example.com',
port: 443
};

var socket = tls.connect(options, function() {
  // Connected
}); 
socket.on('error', function(err) {
  // on error
});
```

Find more information [here](http://node.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/tls/#tls_event_secureconnect)